# Stored Procedure if Exist with dynamically table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem here, I'm searching in stackoverflow but still not find the best way

i have a stored procedure (SP) like this

> DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(max), @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max) 
>   SET @table = @meta+'_prize4winner'
>
> SET @SQLQuery = 'if exists (Select * from [dbo].' + @table + ' where idCampaignLog =''' + convert(nvarchar, @ID) +''') exec InsertC2CWinner''' + convert(nvarchar, @meta) +''','''+ convert(nvarchar, @ID)+''',null  else select ''you lose ''as winStatus'
>
> execute SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQuery

need help how and where to set the output if I want the output if exist 'YOU WIN' else 'You Lose' thx

Comment: Please refer this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105600/how-do-i-dynamically-build-a-like-clause-in-an-executable-sql-stored-procedure-t/3105646#3105646
 add the next line after your exixts condition and make use of output parameter to get return data.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax is like this

```
DECLARE @retval int   
DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(50)  
SELECT @tablename = N'products'  

SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = MAX(ID) FROM ' + @tablename;  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT=@retval OUTPUT;

SELECT @retval;
```